# Run completion: after sequence or group of SKActions

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction, completion

I'm unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong in the following syntax, to get a completion to run.

```
  spriteWhite.run(SKAction.group([moveRight, swipeRight],
       completion: {self.doThisFunction(withThisValue)}))
```

The error is:

> Extra argument "completion" in call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
spriteWhite.run(SKAction.group([moveRight, swipeRight],
           completion: {self.doThisFunction(withThisValue)}))
```

with:

```
spriteWhite.run(SKAction.group([moveRight, swipeRight]),
       completion: { self.doThisFunction(withThisValue) })
```

The issue is due to a syntax error: the parenthesis after the second square brackets to close `SKAction` definition.